# VS Java hadoop WordCount error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, hadoop

I compiled my program, did "jar cf WordCount.jar WordCount*.class" on the class file generated in the bin file, then "hadoop jar ./WordCount.jar WordCount \Users\blast\Desktop\input \Users\blast\Desktop\output\output1". But when I did that this is what was generated. Thanks.

> 2022-02-28 21:58:00,538 INFO
> client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to
> ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:608)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:934)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:848)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getOwner(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:137)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:113)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:148)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1571)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1568)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
> at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1568)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1589)
> at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:59)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

Comment: Make sure you are using java 8 or 11

Comment: Also, make sure your `mapreduce.admin.user.env` is set properly. _"When this value is empty, the command to set execution environment will be OS dependent: For linux, use LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/native. For windows, use PATH = %PATH%;%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%\\bin. "_